# How to make a plugin with special theme system like woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, plugins, themes

How to make a plugin with special theme system like WooCommerce ?
WooCommerce check a theme installed support WooCommerce (WooCommerce directory), for example if page cart exist in directory get it and show with pattern and not exist show cart in general page, is it true?

How to make theme system for my plugin?
Please show in example code? 
Thank you.

Comment: Are you talking about creating a front-end view for your plugin?

Comment: yes i want make a system theme like woocommerce plugin